# Правильное создание кастомных хелперов

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Добрый день. Начал изучать ASP.NET MVC и у меня появился вопрос по поводу хелперов
В книгах и на различных обучающих сайтах подход к созданию внешних хелперов довольно разнится: 
одни советуют создавать расширяющие классы для для класса HtmlHelper и писать его средствами .net, вот простейший пример:

```
    public static class CustomHelperMethods
{
    public static MvcHtmlString UnorderedList(this HtmlHelper helper, string[] items)
    {
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("ul");
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            TagBuilder liTag = new TagBuilder("li");
            liTag.SetInnerText(item);
            tag.InnerHtml += liTag.ToString();
        }
        return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString());
    }
}
```

а другие, такие как сайт docs.microsoft пишут, что лучше использовать папку App_Code и уже там создавать хелперы с помощью обычных тегов, например:

```
@helper HtmlList(string[] items)
{
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
</ul>
}
```

вот меня и интересует вопрос, как правильно создавать внешние хелперы с точки зрения профессиональной разработки и совершенства кода.